# How should board revisions be handled?

Tags: discussion, tags

The boards undergo significant changes across revisions. Is there a need to create separate tags for the different revisions or should we just specify the revision in the question without having separate tags?

The Uno for example underwent multiple changes going from R2 to R3 such as a new microcontroller(Atmega 32 from 16) as well as switching of the FTDI board with a Atmega 16. So, it is possible that many questions relevant for R2 may be obsolete with regard to R3.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Given my understanding of the target audience here, revisions shouldn't be reflected in tags.

Only if the revision is germane to the answer/question should it be raised; No need to force people to try to understand what revision they have just to tag a question.