# Should "Arduino Mega 2560" be considered a revision of the Mega board?

Tags: discussion, tags

We have the tag [mega](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mega). I am almost positive that the OP for the only question so far is referring to the 2560 version of the board. Should we rename it as [arduino-mega-2560](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arduino-mega-2560), leave it because most people won't use the old revision, or add [arduino-mega-original](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arduino-mega-original) or [arduino-mega-classic](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arduino-mega-classic) to refer to the original board?

It seems like the original version would still be used *some*. That's why I like the "original" and "classic" suffixes to the tags so a beginner Arduinoist (is that a word?) who wouldn't know the difference would just use the standard mega tag. However, someone referring to the vintage Arduino board would still be able to ask.

> *[How should board revisions be handled?](https://arduino.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10/how-should-board-revisions-be-handled)* is not a duplicate because the Meta isn't *simply* a revision, it is just a "makeover" of a fairly popular board to keep the branding.

Comment: Mm... honestly I think it depends on one thing: would the question be completely changed if it was referring to the old Mega vs. the new Mega? If yes, probably we need a tag for the old one vs. the new one. If not... leave it.

Comment: I propose the old revision be called [tag:arduino-mega-1280], because that's what he rest of the community calls it

Comment: @TheDoctor Good idea.